# Prevent Image from scaling even though the imageView height = "match_parent"

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this linear layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Policy No."
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now i want the image to not scale but the ImageView to match the height of the parent, the TextView height is set to wrap content and that cant be changed. Also, i can't set the imageView height as wrap_content, since it'll change the height of the overall Linear Layout and i can't afford that.

![Image of problem]https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OXFX.jpg

Now what i want is to have the image's size remain the same as it is the second row, even though the first row's height has increased.

Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: wouldn't it be an option to give the image a fixed height? that seems to be what you want. so like `android:layout_height="5dp"` for example or some other value

Answer (score 0):

add :

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

to your ImageView

Answer (score 0):

To perform no scaling, use

```
android:scaleType="center"
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want, you can do this:
First give your imageviews same fixed height so they won't scale:

```
android:layout_height="25dp"
```

Than put gravity to center_vertical:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

So now you have for each imageview:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
```

It now no longer matters how may lines your textview has, your imageview will stay the same!

Ouput:

[image: Output]

Hope this will help you with your problem.